# Circular Singly Linked List

Tags: java, singly-linked-list, circular-list

So my faculty gave us an assignment on Circular Singly Linked list . I know the concept but somehow i can't seem to put it right in code. So here is my code of a simple circular singly linked list . Will you guys point out what is the mistake i am making . It will be a great help .

My Code-

```
public class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;

    public Node(int data, Node next){
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }


}

public class problem1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Node fourth = new Node(5,null);
    Node third = new Node(3,fourth);
    Node second = new Node(4,third);
    Node head = new Node(3,second);
   for(Node n= head; n!=head;n=n.next)
    {
      System.out.println (n.data);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Hint: where in a circular list do you find a `null` next pointer?

Comment: You just have to close the circle

Answer (score 0):

Hi I believe you need a header and a tail. then set the tail.next to header :) and when ever you create a new node in your list, check to see if header.next() is null and if so just set header.next() to your new node. and always set the newest addition next to tail. I can provide an example if needed. I found a perfect example for you too look at

[How to implement circular linked list in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27767778/how-to-implement-circular-linked-list-in-java)